# Convert rust struct to be used in python using pyo3 in solders

Tags: python, solana-sdk, stake

i am using trying to make python bindings for the solana rust sdk, on the solders repo https://github.com/kevinheavey/solders

there's a crate called primitive here that https://github.com/kevinheavey/solders/tree/main/primitives that contains defined types from the solana rust sdk

for example, https://docs.rs/solana-sdk/latest/src/solana_sdk/signer/presigner.rs.html#17-20 has a wrapper here https://github.com/kevinheavey/solders/blob/main/primitives/src/presigner.rs

i am trying to make a wrapper for the Authorized struct - https://docs.rs/solana-program/1.15.2/src/solana_program/stake/state.rs.html#166

```
#[derive(
    Default,
    Debug,
    Serialize,
    Deserialize,
    PartialEq,
    Eq,
    Clone,
    Copy,
    AbiExample,
    BorshDeserialize,
    BorshSchema,
    BorshSerialize,
)]
pub struct Authorized {
    pub staker: Pubkey,
    pub withdrawer: Pubkey,
}

impl Authorized {
    pub fn auto(authorized: &Pubkey) -> Self {
        Self {
            staker: *authorized,
            withdrawer: *authorized,
        }
    }
    pub fn check(
        &self,
        signers: &HashSet<Pubkey>,
        stake_authorize: StakeAuthorize,
    ) -> Result<(), InstructionError> {
        match stake_authorize {
            StakeAuthorize::Staker if signers.contains(&self.staker) => Ok(()),
            StakeAuthorize::Withdrawer if signers.contains(&self.withdrawer) => Ok(()),
            _ => Err(InstructionError::MissingRequiredSignature),
        }
    }

    pub fn authorize(
        &mut self,
        signers: &HashSet<Pubkey>,
        new_authorized: &Pubkey,
        stake_authorize: StakeAuthorize,
        lockup_custodian_args: Option<(&Lockup, &Clock, Option<&Pubkey>)>,
    ) -> Result<(), InstructionError> {
        match stake_authorize {
            StakeAuthorize::Staker => {
                // Allow either the staker or the withdrawer to change the staker key
                if !signers.contains(&self.staker) && !signers.contains(&self.withdrawer) {
                    return Err(InstructionError::MissingRequiredSignature);
                }
                self.staker = *new_authorized
            }
            StakeAuthorize::Withdrawer => {
                if let Some((lockup, clock, custodian)) = lockup_custodian_args {
                    if lockup.is_in_force(clock, None) {
                        match custodian {
                            None => {
                                return Err(StakeError::CustodianMissing.into());
                            }
                            Some(custodian) => {
                                if !signers.contains(custodian) {
                                    return Err(StakeError::CustodianSignatureMissing.into());
                                }

                                if lockup.is_in_force(clock, Some(custodian)) {
                                    return Err(StakeError::LockupInForce.into());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                self.check(signers, stake_authorize)?;
                self.withdrawer = *new_authorized
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

How do I do it?
I've written till here

```
use crate::Pubkey;
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use solana_sdk::stake::state::Authorized as AuthorizedOriginal;

#[pyclass(module = "solders.authorized", subclass)]
#[derive(
    Default,
    Debug,
    Serialize,
    Deserialize,
    PartialEq,
    Eq,
    Clone,
    Copy
)]
pub struct Authorized(pub AuthorizedOriginal);

#[pymethods]
impl Authorized {
    #[new]
    pub fn auto(authorized: &Pubkey) -> Self {
        AuthorizedOriginal::auto(authorized.as_ref()).into()
    }
}
```

and i'm getting this error when i compile this code -

```
  = note: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
            "_PyBaseObject_Type", referenced from:
                _$LT$pyo3..types..any..PyAny$u20$as$u20$pyo3..type_object..PyTypeInfo$GT$::type_object_raw::h2db497e909a4b3a4 in solders.68yoqbao2mnm9ep.rcgu.o
                _$LT$pyo3..pyclass_init..PyNativeTypeInitializer$LT$T$GT$$u20$as$u20$pyo3..pyclass_init..PyObjectInit$LT$T$GT$$GT$::into_new_object::inner::h07e68564b9db68f0 in libpyo3-ab0e32d5f5768da5.rlib(pyo3-ab0e32d5f5768da5.pyo3.736fad56-cgu.10.rcgu.o)
                _$LT$pyo3..pycell..PyCellBase$LT$U$GT$$u20$as$u20$pyo3..pycell..PyCellLayout$LT$T$GT$$GT$::tp_dealloc::ha6fcbd0f03afe852 in libsolders_primitives-7f7641a8cf0ce1d4.rlib(solders_primitives-7f7641a8cf0ce1d4.416ir2lmtm26mqlw.rcgu.o)
                _$LT$pyo3..types..any..PyAny$u20$as$u20$pyo3..type_object..PyTypeInfo$GT$::type_object_raw::h5bf1340ad547ca49 in libsolders_primitives-7f7641a8cf0ce1d4.rlib(solders_primitives-7f7641a8cf0ce1d4.3rkcworcy5myvmxf.rcgu.o)
            "_PyBool_Type", referenced from:
                _$LT$pyo3..types..boolobject..PyBool$u20$as$u20$pyo3..type_object..PyTypeInfo$GT$::type_object_raw::hc5cdac337a8cc47e in solders.2ht6xn4bqi8as9a9.rcgu.o
                pyo3_ffi::boolobject::PyBool_Check::h69fa466d396b9f61 in libpyo3-ab0e32d5f5768da5.rlib(pyo3-ab0e32d5f5768da5.pyo3.736fad56-cgu.13.rcgu.o)
            "_PyByteArray_Type", referenced from:
                _$LT$pyo3..types..bytearray..PyByteArray$u20$as$u20$pyo3..type_object..PyTypeInfo$GT$::type_object_raw::hbffd1bb5a34fe166 in solders.23htunclfgfjqyjp.rcgu.o
            "_PyBytes_AsString", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::bytes::PyBytes::as_bytes::hd181fd5d881b02b9 in solders.1arnwe90jx0tasrs.rcgu.o
                pyo3::types::bytes::PyBytes::as_bytes::h161a8f26fc54f0f0 in libpyo3-ab0e32d5f5768da5.rlib(pyo3-ab0e32d5f5768da5.pyo3.736fad56-cgu.3.rcgu.o)
                pyo3::types::bytes::PyBytes::as_bytes::hcd42c1a357c0d5ac in libsolders_primitives-7f7641a8cf0ce1d4.rlib(solders_primitives-7f7641a8cf0ce1d4.2xvimkei10l9ezez.rcgu.o)
            "_PyBytes_FromStringAndSize", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::bytes::PyBytes::new::hcb42ca3a660a734c in libpyo3-ab0e32d5f5768da5.rlib(pyo3-ab0e32d5f5768da5.pyo3.736fad56-cgu.3.rcgu.o)
            "_PyBytes_Size", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::bytes::PyBytes::as_bytes::hd181fd5d881b02b9 in solders.1arnwe90jx0tasrs.rcgu.o
                pyo3::types::bytes::PyBytes::as_bytes::h161a8f26fc54f0f0 in libpyo3-ab0e32d5f5768da5.rlib(pyo3-ab0e32d5f5768da5.pyo3.736fad56-cgu.3.rcgu.o)
                pyo3::types::bytes::PyBytes::as_bytes::hcd42c1a357c0d5ac in libsolders_primitives-7f7641a8cf0ce1d4.rlib(solders_primitives-7f7641a8cf0ce1d4.2xvimkei10l9ezez.rcgu.o)
            "_PyBytes_Type", referenced from:
                _$LT$pyo3..types..bytes..PyBytes$u20$as$u20$pyo3..type_object..PyTypeInfo$GT$::type_object_raw::h31269ba20521ccfe in solders.1arnwe90jx0tasrs.rcgu.o
            "_PyCFunction_NewEx", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::function::PyCFunction::internal_new::h907953e54bf0eb60 in libpyo3-ab0e32d5f5768da5.rlib(pyo3-ab0e32d5f5768da5.pyo3.736fad56-cgu.11.rcgu.o)
            "_PyDict_GetItem", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::dict::PyDict::get_item::h3d97bdb65c08dd78 in solders.3nmrijp6e84qzy81.rcgu.o
            "_PyDict_New", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::dict::PyDict::new::hbb820c84aae4f03b in libpyo3-ab0e32d5f5768da5.rlib(pyo3-ab0e32d5f5768da5.pyo3.736fad56-cgu.8.rcgu.o)
            "_PyDict_Next", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::dict::PyDictIterator::next_unchecked::ha6d6311ed07653e5 in libpyo3-ab0e32d5f5768da5.rlib(pyo3-ab0e32d5f5768da5.pyo3.736fad56-cgu.8.rcgu.o)
            "_PyDict_SetItem", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::dict::PyDict::set_item::h8ed16cd86bfa178c in solders.3nmrijp6e84qzy81.rcgu.o
                pyo3::types::dict::PyDict::set_item::had6f6258b8d904a2 in solders.3nmrijp6e84qzy81.rcgu.o
            "_PyDict_Size", referenced from:
                pyo3::types::dict::PyDict::_len::h22e7d9ac36fab485 in libpyo3-ab0e32d5f5768da5.rlib(pyo3-ab0e32d5f5768da5.pyo3.736fad56-cgu.8.rcgu.o)
            "_PyDict_Type", referenced from:
                _$LT$pyo3..types..dict..PyDict$u20$as$u20$pyo3..type_object..PyTypeInfo$GT$::type_object_raw::hc578fc4fff0cbb42 in solders.u221hiuz951ys4q.rcgu.o
            "_PyErr_Fetch", referenced from:
                pyo3::err::PyErr::take::he6df2c393cbbc534 in libpyo3-ab0e32d5f5768da5.rlib(pyo3-ab0e32d5f5768da5.pyo3.736fad56-cgu.3.rcgu.o)
            "_PyErr_GivenExceptionMatches", referenced from:
                pyo3::err::PyErr::is_instance::ha64f9cd09285ae5a in libpyo3-ab0e32d5f5768da5.rlib(pyo3-ab0e32d5f5768da5.pyo3.736fad56-cgu.3.rcgu.o)
            "_PyErr_NewExceptionWithDoc", referenced from:
                pyo3::err::PyErr::new_type::h96e7cd58b67184f4 in libpyo3-ab0e32d5f5768da5.rlib(pyo3-ab0e32d5f5768da5.pyo3.736fad56-cgu.3.rcgu.o)
            "_PyErr_NormalizeException", referenced from:
```

no idea what this means. what do i do?

Comment: Solders author here, unfortunately I have never encountered this error lol. Are you getting this error when you run `maturin develop` and `maturin build`? And have you tried running `cargo clean`?

Comment: nope, i get this when i run `cargo build`. im using a 2021 M1 Pro machine. yup i did run `cargo clean && cargo build` still the same error

Comment: Do you still get the error when running `maturin develop`?

Comment: nope, i trying to make a primitive for the `Authorized` struct and maybe i'm doing something wrong there?

Comment: I suggest opening a PR on the Solders repo. I'll run the CI and see if it gets the same error or if it's something weird on your machine. Then I'll just close the PR